# How can I get opening and closing balance using function for partner ledger report in odoo-11

Tags: odoo-11

I want opening and closing balance w.r.t. date_from and date_to in partner ledger report in odoo-11 using function. How can I get?

```py
class OpeningBalance(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'res.partner'
    # _inherit = 'account.common.partner.report'
    def opbal(self, partner_id,date):
        query = """
                SELECT partner_id, SUM(debit) AS sumdr, SUM(credit) AS sumcr
                FROM account_move_line AS aml 
                WHERE 
                aml.partner_id = %s
                AND aml.date < '%s' %(partner_id,date)"""

        self.env.cr.execute(query)
        get = cr.fetchall()
        get[0].sumcr
        get[0].sumdr

        bal =  sumdr - sumcr
        return bal
```

I want bal returns opening balance upto date that enter.

Comment: I want to know the initial balance through XML-RPC...